# T-SQL Create a new table from results of the same table depending on column data

Tags: sql-server, join

I am sorry for the kind of ambiguous title up there but I don't think there is an easy way to explain what I am trying to do here. 
I have the table below in my SQL database:

```
╔═══════╦══════════════════════════╦════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID    ║ Short Name               ║ Day        ║ CSFB           ║ SomeNumberHere ║ DCR            ║
║ 58144 ║ PERSVN_L26_C_1           ║ 06/10/2014 ║ 588            ║ 588            ║ 15727          ║
║ 58145 ║ PERSVN_L26_C_1           ║ 07/10/2014 ║ 587            ║ 587            ║ 16733          ║
║ 58146 ║ PERSVN_L18_C_1           ║ 08/10/2014 ║ 640            ║ 640            ║ 15109          ║
║ 58250 ║ PETERLORANGESVEI_L18_C_1 ║ 12/10/2014 ║ 53             ║ 53             ║ 2765           ║
║ 58251 ║ PHILIPPEDERSEN_L08_A2_1  ║ 03/10/2014 ║ 24             ║ 24             ║ 1003           ║
╚═══════╩══════════════════════════╩════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩════════
```

I want to create an extra row in this table, which will be calculated by adding the DCR + CSFB row numbers IF the short name contains **L26**, DCR - CSFB IF the short name contains **L18** and DCR / CSFB IF the short name contains **L08**.

The result, would look like this:

```
╔═══════╦══════════════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID    ║ Short Name               ║ Calculation ║ Day        ║ CSFB  ║ SomeNumberHere ║ DCR   ║
║ 58144 ║ PERSVN_L26_C_1           ║ {CSFB+DCR}  ║ 06/10/2014 ║ 588   ║ 588            ║ 15727 ║
║ 58145 ║ PERSVN_L26_C_1           ║ {CSFB+DCR}  ║ 07/10/2014 ║ 587   ║ 587            ║ 16733 ║
║ 58146 ║ PERSVN_L18_C_1           ║ {CSFB-DCR}  ║ 08/10/2014 ║ 640   ║ 640            ║ 15109 ║
║ 58250 ║ PETERLORANGESVEI_L18_C_1 ║ {CSFB-DCR}  ║ 12/10/2014 ║ 53    ║ 53             ║ 2765  ║
║ 58251 ║ PHILIPPEDERSEN_L08_A2_1  ║ {CSFB/DCR}  ║ 03/10/2014 ║ 24    ║ 24             ║ 1003  ║
╚═══════╩══════════════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩════════════════╩═══════╝
```

Can you help me go about it? 
One way is to create three different tmp tables with a `"where [Short Name] like '%Lxx%'"` 
and then merge them together, but I am trying to avoid that. A stored procedure would do you think ? Thanks for the help

Comment: So what you really want is a derived column, not a new new row correct? Take a look at the case expression. There is no need to create 3 temp tables at all. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want the calculation performed per row? If so this query should be what you want. If you need it in the table permanently you can use the case expression as source for a computed column.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a163/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [Short Name] varchar(24), [Day] datetime, [CSFB] int, [SomeNumberHere] int, [DCR] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Short Name], [Day], [CSFB], [SomeNumberHere], [DCR])
VALUES
    (58144, 'PERSVN_L26_C_1', '2014-06-10 02:00:00', 588, 588, 15727),
    (58145, 'PERSVN_L26_C_1', '2014-07-10 02:00:00', 587, 587, 16733),
    (58146, 'PERSVN_L18_C_1', '2014-08-10 02:00:00', 640, 640, 15109),
    (58250, 'PETERLORANGESVEI_L18_C_1', '2014-12-10 01:00:00', 53, 53, 2765),
    (58251, 'PHILIPPEDERSEN_L08_A2_1', '2014-03-10 01:00:00', 24, 24, 1003)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    [Short Name], 
    CASE 
       WHEN [Short Name] LIKE '%L26%' THEN DCR+CSFB  
       WHEN [Short Name] LIKE '%L18%' THEN DCR-CSFB  
       WHEN [Short Name] LIKE '%L08%' THEN DCR/CSFB  
    END AS Calculation,
    Day,
    CSFB,
    SomeNumberHere,
    DCR  
FROM TABLE1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a163/1/0)**:

```
|    ID |               SHORT NAME | CALCULATION |                             DAY | CSFB | SOMENUMBERHERE |   DCR |
|-------|--------------------------|-------------|---------------------------------|------|----------------|-------|
| 58144 |           PERSVN_L26_C_1 |       16315 |     June, 10 2014 02:00:00+0000 |  588 |            588 | 15727 |
| 58145 |           PERSVN_L26_C_1 |       17320 |     July, 10 2014 02:00:00+0000 |  587 |            587 | 16733 |
| 58146 |           PERSVN_L18_C_1 |       14469 |   August, 10 2014 02:00:00+0000 |  640 |            640 | 15109 |
| 58250 | PETERLORANGESVEI_L18_C_1 |        2712 | December, 10 2014 01:00:00+0000 |   53 |             53 |  2765 |
| 58251 |  PHILIPPEDERSEN_L08_A2_1 |          41 |    March, 10 2014 01:00:00+0000 |   24 |             24 |  1003 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add a computed column to the table, with the computed value being based on a CASE statement.

ie:

```
ALTER tableName
ADD [Calculation] DECIMAL(14,5) AS CASE WHEN [Short Name] LIKE '%L26%' THEN DCR + CSFB
                                      WHEN [Short Name] LIKE '%L18%' THEN DCR - CSFB
                                      WHEN [Short Name] LIKE '%L08%' THEN DCR / CSFB
                                      ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thank you James, this is a very elegant approach indeed! The only thing is that the real calculation I'm using, is also a CASE statement that requires data from different tables. From what I read, this is illegal to use in a computed column. 
    I also found that I can declare a user-defined function and use it as the computed value, but I just have too many variables to create 50 functions. Is there an alternative to that?

Comment: @user3702185 If its data coming from different tables then a VIEW might be what you're looking for. Can have computed columns from different source tables then!